# Is there any Gtk+ 3 port of the Redmond theme?

Tags: themes, gtk3, gtk-2

I have the gtk2 version of Redmond installed, but it doesn't work for programs using gtk3. Redmond looks like this:

[image]

Or are there any gtk3 themes similar to redmond?

Answer (score 1):

Look for Redmond like themes here http://b00merang.weebly.com/redmond-collection.html

Answer (score 0):

The most similar theme for GTK3 right now is this:
[GTK3 Mist](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Mist-Redmond?content=155580)

If you feel adventurous you can make your own based on this one [Making GTK3 themes](http://worldofgnome.org/making-gtk3-themes-part-1-basics/)